# how to place cells and multicell with column format in fpdf

Tags: php, fpdf

There are several solution to create columns in fpdf and where you can put either multicells or cell
But problem is

These solution are not working for
single multicell and cells like in this image

**column format image**
[image]

```
//Column 1
$x = $this->x;
$y = $this->y;
$push_right = 0;
$w=130;
$this->MultiCell($w = 130,10,"This is a test line.This is a test line.",0,'L',0);


//Columns2
$push_right += $w;
$this->SetXY($x + $push_right, $y);
$this->SetFont($this->font,'B',10);
$this->Cell($w = 30,10,"SHORT LINE",1,'L',1);



//Column 3
$push_right += $w;
$this->SetXY($x + $push_right, $y);

$this->Cell(0,10,"SHORT TEXT",1,'R',1);

//cell for column 3
$push_right += 130;
$this->SetXY($x + $push_right, $y);
$this->SetFont($this->font,'B',10);
$this->Cell($w = 30,10,"SHORT TEXT",1,'L',0);


//cell for column 3
$push_right += $w;
$this->SetXY($x + $push_right, $y);

$this->Cell(0,10,"SHORT TEXT",1,'R',0);
```